# Check if a array have a value on specific positions

Tags: php, arrays

I'm getting the index keys of a haystack array containing many needles. The array contains another words too, but I don't need them to be checked.

So I'm using `array_keys($haystack, &needle);` to create an array containing the position of each needle.

Now I need to check in another array if on the positions from the array I've obtained by using `array_keys` I have a specific value. I need some ideas about how to do this.

The main idea:

```
$check = array_keys($haystack, &needle);
*now I need to check if I have a value on the positions from $check on $array2*
```

Then I need to do an action if it is found on a position (it doesn't matter on what position).

Comment: Show us the array you are talking about.

Comment: let's say the `$haystack` array contains `needle, sofa, cake, needle, needle` and the `$array2` array contains `dog, cat, mouse, dog, goose`. So I have needle on positions 0, 3 and 4. I need to check if in `$array2` on the same positions I have the word `goose`. If it is, I'll echo "Found!".

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do `array_keys();`.

You can do it like this.

```
foreach ($haystack as $needle) {
  if ($needle == $your_value) {
   /* your stuff */
 }
}
```

Comment: I need to check if I have that value on same position as $needle on the second array.

Comment: let's say the `$haystack` array contains `needle, sofa, cake, needle, needle` and the `$array2` array contains `dog, cat, mouse, dog, goose`. So I have needle on positions 0, 3 and 4. I need to check if in `$array2` on the same positions I have the word goose. If it is, I'll echo "Found!"

Comment: well, I can't help you from here. I am sorry, just a beginner

Answer (score 0):

It'll work with this if it's an associative:

```
foreach($array1 as $k => $v)
{
  if(isset($array2[$k]))
  {
    // Your thing
  }
}
```

If you want to find based on the exact key index:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($array1); $i++)
{
  if($array1[$i] == "needle" && isset($array2[$i]))
  {
    if($array2[$i] == "goose")
    {
      // Your thing
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is good, but not exactly what I'm looking for.
Let's say the `$haystack` array contains `needle, sofa, cake, needle, needle` and the `$array2` array contains `dog, cat, mouse, dog, goose`. So I have needle on positions 0, 3 and 4. I need to check if in `$array`2 on the same positions I have the word goose. If it is, I'll echo "Found!"

Comment: @Rawrrr1337 Check my second `for` loop. This applies to a static situation and if your arrays are different in length and content, there is going to be another scenario for it.